# Zend - doctrine 2 querybuilder help

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

i want to use this:

```
$query = $this->_doctrine->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('u')
        ->from('\Entities\Users', 'l')
        ->leftJoin('l.userentities', 'u')
        ->getQuery();
return $info = $query->getResult();
```

and my users entity is:

```
namespace Entities\Users;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="users")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Users extends \Entities\AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(name="userid", type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $userid;
      /** @Column(name="itemid", type="integer") */

    protected $itemid;
}
```

and my user entities entity class contains:

```
namespace Entities\Users;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="userentities")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Userentities extends \Entities\AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(name="entityid", type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $entityid;
      /** @Column(name="userid", type="integer") */

    protected $userid;

     /** @Column(name="crb", type="string") */

    protected $crb;

}
```

i tried put this into the entity but no joy
         * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="userid")
         * @JoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="userid")

1 user has many user entities..

and i get this error:

Error: Class Entities\Users has no association named Users

i just want to do a left join with users to usersentities..

how can i doa left join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this annotation in your Userentities class for the $userid field:

```
/**
 * @var Entities\Userentities
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="userentities", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $userid;
```

and this annotation in your Users class with a new field called $userentities:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Userentities", mappedBy="userid", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $userentities;
```

Comment: heyyep it works.. i add a user and i can select a list of userentities in that table... but when i do a doctrine 2 query.. it shows all the userentities columns along with the left join tbale users but its all null....   i tried to validate my schema and it says:  [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.     is the problem why my left join queries is bringing null values?

Comment: Did you use the Doctrine CLI to update your schema? orm:schema-tool:update --force

Comment: Hi. Yep, that's the exact command. But after reading I don't think that's why it's not pulling the joined values. It should pull all values but it's showing the main left table and then then joined table with null values